# Bluetooth LE Proximity Profile with BlueZ

Tags: wireless, bluetooth

BlueZ seems to be not that good documented. I'm trying to run the PXP (Proximity) profile on my Raspberry Pi. I installed D-Bus 1.8 and bluez 5.17.

I know that the proximity profile is supported by bluez but i have no idea how to execute it.

Maybe someone here is more experienced and can give quick instructions.

- rasbian (Linux version 3.10.25+)
- USB BLE Dongle bt400